# How to process groups of duplicate fields and organize by common field key - PHP / Array

Tags: php, javascript

Looking to mimic what's going on on this website where you can add multiple field groups:   When you click "add another card", it duplicates the field -- I've got this covered with jquery and `clone()`.  However, if you input two gift cards with the same amount, on the next step they've combined the quantities for those gift cards into one group.  So here's a scenario that I'm facing and the output that I would like to see:

User Input:

```
Field Group 1 -- Amount: $100 Quantity: 1
Field Group 2 -- Amount: $75 Quantity: 2
Field Group 3 -- Amount: $100 Quantity: 1
```

Desired Output on Next Page:

```
$100 Gift Card Group: 2
$75 Gift Card Group: 2
```

I've been searching for different ways to do this and can't find anything, please help!!

Comment: Please show us the result of `print_r($_POST);` on the result page.

Answer (score 0):

For the inputs, I would use names like denomination[], quantity[], since we are processing arrays. On the next page, do a print_r() on $_POST, and then you can do a foreach() loop to combine quantities of the same denomination.

Now, suppose $foo is our (cleaned up) $_POST. **Please perform a pre-processing loop to clean up the inputs; e.g. discarding invalid denominations/quantities as required.**

Once this is done, we end up with $foo like:

```
<?php
// cleaned up $_POST
$foo = array(
    'denomination' => array(100, 75, 100),
    'quantity' => array(1, 2, 1),
);

$bar = array();
foreach ($foo['denomination'] as $d => $denomination) {
    if (array_key_exists($denomination, $bar)) { // denomination exists
       $bar[$denomination] += $foo['quantity'][$d];
    } else { // new denomination
       $bar[$denomination] = $foo['quantity'][$d];
    }
}
print_r($bar); die; // debug
?>
```

The output is:

```
Array(
    [100] => 2,
    [75] => 2
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help - here are the array prints output to the next page. How would I go about grouping and combining them by the denomination?

$_POST['denomination'] output:
Array
(
    [0] => 100
    [1] => 75
    [2] => 100
)

$_POST['quantity'] output:
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 1
)

Comment: Sure thing. Please checkbox my answer if you like it!